# Changing Minecraft entity rendering distance

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've noticed that, on some various servers I play on, entities are not rendered even if I am a short distance away, like ~40 blocks. Other servers I play on seem to be capable of rendering entities at enormous distances. I don't believe it's a server performance thing, as some of the more higher-performance networks I've been on, like Hypixel, have this short render distance as well.

Is there a way to edit this distance? It'd improve various aspects of my gameplay.

possibly related: yesterday, when setting up a small Spigot server on my computer, I noticed "view-distance" (or a similar name) in the server.properties file. Is this the entity render distance? It most likely isn't the regular render distance, because that's easily changeable on clientside from player to player.

Comment: Rendering distance is a client setting, but can be limited by the server (which may account for the differences you see). [This guy](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/modification-development/2246866-changing-an-entities-render-distance) seems to have figured out how to change it, and I'm guessing he learned what he knows from a more authoritative resource that I can't seem to find. Perhaps it is buried among [these tutorials](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Tutorials)?

Comment: did you ever consider that perhaps one of the *reasons* certain servers are higher-performing is that they limit entity render distance.

Answer (score 3):

On spigot, it's depending on the `entity-tracing-range` in `spigot.yml`, but if you're using OptiFine, the it could be multiplied by a number depending on your settings.